# php check time format with preg_match

Tags: php, regex

I want in a php script to check if a given time do have this format : hh:mm using regex and preg_match.
I tried this solution:

```
$time="12:59";
if(preg_match("/(2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):[0-5][0-9]/", $time)){print('right');}
```

But problem is , this solution is not really correct because it works also with xxxx12:59xxxx how to fix that (it looks only to the first two digit before the : and the two next of it how to tell that the given time supposed to have exactly 2 number then : then 2 number ?)

Comment: What does the `xxxx` mean?

Comment: @AvinashRaj any character, presumably...

Comment: you mean it would be, `123456:598753`

Comment: @AvinashRaj yeah, OP typed it wrong though -- the question's given regex actually matches `xxxx12:59xxxx` (not `12xxxx:59xxxx`). I just fixed it for the OP.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté  yeah u'r right good to notice :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `^` (beginning of string) and `$` (end of string) anchors to your regex.

```
if(preg_match("/^(2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):[0-5][0-9]$/", $time)) /*...*/
```

---

Just for clarification's sake, `xxx12:59xxx` passes OP's test because [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) returns whether the string *contains* a match for the given regex, not whether the whole string matches the given regex. To achieve the latter behavior, your regex just needs to be more specific and use the start and end of string anchors.

Comment: didnt check other ans before posting.anyways this is correct.

Comment: could you please develop a little more the use of ^ and $

Comment: great :) +1 for the explanation !

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following one:

```
$time="12:59";
if(preg_match("/(1[012]|0[0-9]):[0-5][0-9]/", $time))
{
     // success validation
}
```

Comment: Read the question 'til the end, your regex will fail the outlined use case in the question.

Answer (score 0):

For 12 hour format

```
preg_match("/(1[012]|0[0-9]):[0-5][0-9]/", $time);
```

For 24 hour format

```
preg_match("/(2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):[0-5][0-9]/", $time);
```

Comment: Read the question 'til the end, your regex will fail the outlined use case in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid regex and use DateTime method [`createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php). It returns false if the input doesn't match the format.

```
$time="12:59";
if(DateTime::createFromFormat('h:m', $time)) {
        echo 'right!';
}
```

if you need to allow 24-hour as well, you can change it to:

```
if(DateTime::createFromFormat('h:m', $time) ||  
  (DateTime::createFromFormat('H:m', $time) && 
   !array_sum(DateTime::getLastErrors())
  ) {
        echo 'right!';
}
```

Since `createFromFormat` allows shifting for 24-hour format (so 24:30 converts to 00:30 + 1 day), the check on `getLastErrors()` checks if this occurred so in that scenario it still evaluates to false.

Comment: good alternative too but didnt worked for me exp:`$time="58:29";
if(DateTime::createFromFormat('h:m', $time) ||  
   DateTime::createFromFormat('H:m', $time)) {
        echo 'right!';
} //output right`

Comment: It looks like the method treats 24-99 as a rollover to next day. Probably a bug, so I created one : https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67921

Comment: Updated with workaround to avoid overflow shifting. The 12 hour format doesn't need extra check.